# PostgreSQL setting only a specific table to a character set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have found a way to setup a database to a character set but how do I set it up so that I have certain character sets on different tables?

I need to setup one table to support IPA characters and another to support hebrew script.

Comment: The first thing is to be clear on the difference between character sets (which glyphs you want to be able to show) and encoding schemes (how a set of glyphs is stored as a set of bytes). They are related in that each encoding scheme can be limited in the glyphs it supports. As @erlx says, you probably need some form of UTF (and UTF-8 is the only supported by PostgreSQL so far) to support the desired range of glyphs. A related issue is `collation`, which you might want to look at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have your database encoded as UTF-8 to be able to store data
in various charsets.

More about [charsets](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/multibyte.html)

If for some reason you need to use SQL_ASCII you might need to change your client_encoding
depending on the charset you may need to read.